# Passing the pk from url to CreateView form_valid

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I want to pass pk of other model from URL to my CreateView form. How to do that? Could you help me? When I'm passing specific id it works, but I want to get the pk automatycly, from url.
My `views.py`:

```
class ScenarioDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Scenario

class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = [
        'commentText'
    ]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.commentAuthor = self.request.user
        form.instance.commentDate = datetime.now()
        form.instance.commentScenario = Scenario.objects.get(pk=1) #there is my problem
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

My `url.py`:

```
path('scenario/<int:pk>/', ScenarioDetailView.as_view(), name='scenario-detail'),
```

Also my model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    commentText = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    commentScenario = models.ForeignKey(Scenario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    commentAuthor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    commentDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Any suggestions?

Edit//
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value from [**`self.kwargs`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.setup) dictionary. For example:

```
# url
path('comment/<int:scenario_id>/', CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='comment-create'),

# view
class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = [
        'commentText'
    ]
    def form_valid(self, form):
            form.instance.commentAuthor = self.request.user
            form.instance.commentDate = datetime.now()
            form.instance.commentScenario = Scenario.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('scenario_id')) #there is my problem
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: I changed it, but now I have an error: ```Reverse for 'comment-create' with no arguments not found.```

Comment: where are you initiating the reverse? Can you please share the full error stacktrace?

Comment: ```Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'comment-create' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['comment/(?P<scenario_id>[0-9]+)/$']```

Comment: My ```urls.py``` looks like: ```urlpatterns = [
    path('', ScenarioListView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('scenario/<int:pk>/', ScenarioDetailView.as_view(), name='scenario-detail'),
    path('scenario/<int:pk>/delete/', ScenarioDeleteView.as_view(), name='scenario-delete'),
    path('scenario/new/', ScenarioCreateView.as_view(), name='scenario-create'),
    path('comment/<int:scenario_id>/', CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='comment-create'),
]```

Comment: can you please share the code for ScenarioDetailView?

Comment: Updated, at the top.

Comment: Um, I am not getting the part where its causing the issue. Possible scenario, in template, you need to change the url `{% url 'comment-create' scenairo_id=scenario.pk %}`. If you are calling from view, then reverse should be called like this `reverse('comment-create', args=[scenario.id])`. More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

Comment: Hm, but I don't have this url in my template :/

Comment: can you share the full error trace from top to bottom please? if you are django debug mode, it should show an error page

Comment: Ok, I upload a photo of error page at the top. Hope this help!

Comment: thanks, but it did not help. By the way, is there any success url with `comment-create`? And also how are you connecting to CommentCreateView from other places? can you please share those codes?

Comment: No, I reload the page in js after form submit. Is it the reason?

Comment: I am not sure. In the code, there should be a reference to `comment-create`, either via reverse, or `{% url ... %}` or `success_url` in view, or even absolute url. Can you find such references and share here please?

Comment: O, I found! ```<form method="POST" action="{% url 'comment-create' %}" onsubmit="setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload();},10)">
                <div class="center"><h5>Add:</h5></div>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ newComment }}
                <div class="center">
                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" value="Submit">Publish</button>
                </div>
        </form>``` Is it the reason? Should I change it?

Comment: You can change it to `{% url 'comment-create' scenairo_id=scenario.pk %}` . you need to pass scenario object via context(probably you already have it)

Comment: No, just in my ```ScenarioDetailView``` as on top. Now I change it and I have another error: ```Reverse for 'comment-create' with keyword arguments '{'scenairo_id': 34}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['comment/(?P<scenario_id>[0-9]+)/$']```

Comment: Try changing the url in `urls.py` to `comment/(?P<scenario_id>\d+)/$`

Comment: Didn't work, now its ```Reverse for 'comment-create' with keyword arguments '{'scenairo_id': 34}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['comment/\\(\\?P(?P<scenario_id>[^/]+)\\\\d\\+\\)/\\$$']``` :/

Comment: Sorry, my bad. remove the changes based on my last comment. Can you please try this url in template: `{% url 'comment-create' scenario.pk %}`?